# Process exited with return value 3221225725. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, while, dev-c++

Soy nuevo en C++ y tengo que hacer el programa de un parchís para el cual la mayor parte del código se encuentra en este bucle while, que por alguna razón **funciona bien durante varios ciclos, normalmente 6 o 7**, pero al cabo de unos cuantos crashea y se acaba el programa retornando un valor muy alto.

Estoy casi seguro de que la parte que le hace crashear probablemente sea este "Press Enter to Continue".

```
    cout<<endl<<"Pulsa enter para tirar el dado"<<endl;
    numAleatorio = sacarNumAleatorio();
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"El resultado del dado es: "<<numAleatorio<<endl;
```

De todas formas si lo queréis ver, este es el código del while entero. ¿A alguien se le ocurre alguna idea de qué puede estar fallando?

```
while(partidaTerminada == false){
    
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<68; i++){
        cout<<mapa[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<68; i++){
        cout<<posicion[i];
    }
    
    if(turnoJugador1 == false && turnoJugador2 == false){
        turnoJugador1 = true;
    }
    
    if(turnoJugador1 == true){
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Es el turno del jugador 1, representado por el color "<<jugador1;
    }
    
    else if(turnoJugador2 == true){
        cout<<endl<<endl<<"Es el turno del jugador 2, representado por el color "<<jugador2<<endl;
    }
    
    cout<<endl<<"Pulsa enter para tirar el dado"<<endl;
    numAleatorio = sacarNumAleatorio();
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"El resultado del dado es: "<<numAleatorio<<endl;
    
    if(turnoJugador2==true){
        posicion[posicionJugador2] = '\0';  
        posicionJugador2 += numAleatorio;
        
        if(posicionJugador2 > 68){
            posicionJugador2 -= 68;
        }
        posicion[posicionJugador2] = jugador2;
        turnoJugador1 = true;
        turnoJugador2 = false;
        
        }
    
    else if(turnoJugador1==true){
        posicion[posicionJugador1] = '\0';  
        posicionJugador1 += numAleatorio;
        
        if(posicionJugador1 > 68){
            posicionJugador1 -= 68;
        }
        posicion[posicionJugador1] = jugador1;
        turnoJugador2 = true;
        turnoJugador1 = false;
        }
}
```

Si alguien de vosotros pudiese ayudarme, se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Si el programa falla en momentos aleatorios mostrando datos aleatorios, sin duda estás leyendo y/o escribiendo en memoria que no te pertenece.

Comment: ¿Y cómo podría arreglarlo?

Comment: sin la declaración e inicialización de las variables `mapa`, `posicion`, ... y sin conocer la función `sacarNumAleatorio()` es complicado decirte

Comment: El número de error que pones en el título, al pasarlo a hexadecimal, es el `0xc00000fd` que indica que ha ocurrido un _stack overflow_. O sea, la pila se ha llenado. Eso es síntoma de una recursión infinita (una función que se llama a sí misma). En el fragmento de código que has pegado no se observa nada de eso, pero probablemente lo tengas por algún otro sitio. Mira bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia, era eso, ya está arreglado! En la función para sacar un numAleatorio, puse una condición de que si el dado salía 0, volviese a llamar a la función desde la misma función, y se ve que eso provocaba un stack overflow cada vez que el dado sacaba 0 y se daba esa condición. Gracias! :)